# vue/test-utils - how to test composition api?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, ts-jest, vue-test-utils

unable to test setup component

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
 ... logic ...
</script>
```

Let's say I have a component that looks something like this:

```
RegistrationComponents.vue
<template>
        <input
          maxlength="255"
          @input="ch"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          class="input email_address"
          autocapitalize="off"
          :class="{ 'bg-status-red-border': errorEmail[0] }"
        />
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useFetch } from "@/hook/fetch/fetch";
import PasswordComponent from "../password/passwordComponent.vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

... and more logic ...

</script>


test.spec.ts:

import RegistrationComponents from "@/components/registration/RegistrationComponents.vue";
import { expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

test("1. The user with the data exists in the system. my@mail.com", async () => {
  const wrapper = await mount(RegistrationComponents, {
    global: {
      mocks: {
        $tc: (msg: string) => msg,
      },
    },
  });

  const emailInput = wrapper.find<HTMLInputElement>(".email_address");

  emailInput.setValue("my@mail.com");

  expect(emailInput.element.value).toBe("my@mail.com");
});
```

when trying to test such a component, an error occurs:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

as it turned out, the problem is that there is no template in such a component

How can this problem be solved? all my components are written in setup

Do I really have to rewrite everything into class components? Is there really no other way to solve this?

```
enter code here
```

please help me solve this problem

Comment: What you show is not a functional component but composition api, sticking to the right terms makes it easy to search for the relevant info. " trying to test such a component" - test in which way? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If the problem is related to the lack of a template it could be that there's a problem with .vue file loader, this depends on your setup, which is again, unknown. Vue test utils official docs perfectly describe how composition api comps are tested

Comment: at least one example is possible where testing with composition api would be shown. So far I haven't been able to find anything

Comment: This way https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/a-crash-course.html . As long as you don't test the behaviour and not implementation as suggested here https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/easy-to-test.html#do-not-test-implementation-details , it absolutely doesn't matter which api you use

Comment: I look at the documentation, and not one example with setup

Comment: Please, check the previous comment. This "it absolutely doesn't matter which api you use" means that it doesn't matter if you use setup function or not, as long as you test the way the docs describe.

Comment: in my updated code, the error keeps happening. Ahead of that, if you start the server, then everything works fine.

Comment: The way the test is written is ok, this shouldn't be a concern no more. As said, it's your project setup that matters, which is unknown. Already mentioned this in the first comment, you didn't respond to that. Jest environment is mostly unrelated to how your main app is cofigured - is it Vue CLI or else?  If you believe the error is caused by component template (there are no proofs of that) then this means that Jest is not properly configured to be used with Vue. Probably old vue-loader version. Or anything else that the question didn't mention.